# Go and gorilla sessions in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, session, cookies, go

I'm making a simple web app using Go, gorilla for sessions and routing, and mustache for templates.  I'm having an issue with the login involving, I believe, a problem with IE accepting the cookie.  The problem only occurs with Internet Explorer, but otherwise the login works perfectly in Chrome.  Here is my code:

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/performance", Index)
    r.HandleFunc("/performance/login", Login)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":5901", r))
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, "performance")
    if session.Values["username"] == nil {
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/performance/login", http.StatusSeeOther)
    }
    dict := session.Values
    fmt.Fprintf(w, mustache.RenderFileInLayout("templates/index.html", "templates/basepage.html", dict))
}

func Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        results := 0
        r.ParseForm()
        u := r.FormValue("username")
        pass := r.FormValue("password")
        p := PassEncrypt(pass)
        q := map[string]string{}
        rows, err := db.Query("SELECT username, name, title FROM user WHERE (username=$1) AND (password=$2)", u, p)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for rows.Next() {
            var username string
            var name string
            var title string
            if err := rows.Scan(&username, &name, &title); err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            q["username"] = username
            q["name"] = name
            q["title"] = title
            results++
        }
        if results > 0 {
            session, _ := store.Get(r, "performance")
            session.Options = &sessions.Options{
                MaxAge: 900,
            }
            session.Values["username"] = q["username"]
            session.Values["name"] = q["name"]
            session.Values["title"] = q["title"]
            session.Save(r, w)
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/performance", http.StatusSeeOther)
        } else {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/performance/login", http.StatusSeeOther)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, mustache.RenderFileInLayout("templates/login.html", "templates/basepage.html", nil))
    }
}
```

When logging in using IE the user is redirected right back to the login page because the session value "username" is nil, while in Chrome the username is correctly defined and the index page is served.  For some reason IE is not accepting the cookie, yet I changed all settings in IE to allow cookies from any site.  Do I need to change one of the cookie options or add something to the cookie other than "MaxAge" for IE to accept it?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would've been nice if you'd shorten your code so that it is easily reproducible. [I did that for you this time (more or less)](http://play.golang.org/p/jvZ5lKqbWE).

Comment: Sorry about that, was worried I'd post too little - this is my first SO question.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to define the cookie's path in your options.
The following options struct should do the trick:

```
session.Options = &sessions.Options{
    Path: "/performance",
}
```

Said option limits the cookie's availability to the given path, for the whole page
use `"/"`.

Note that the `max-age` setting is [not supported by IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/08/20/wininet-ie-cookie-internals-faq.aspx):

> [...] Internet Explorer (including IE8) does not attempt to support any RFC for cookies.
>   WinINET (the network stack below IE) has cookie implementation based on the pre-RFC Netscape draft spec for cookies. This means that directives like max-age, versioned cookies, etc, are not supported in any version of Internet Explorer.

By the way, you don't need a `MaxAge` for session cookies (from the [IE manual on cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533693%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
(expires=date;)
    If you set no expiration date on a cookie, it expires when the browser 
    closes. If you set an expiration date, the cookie is saved across browser 
    sessions. If you set an expiration date in the past, the cookie is deleted. 
    Use Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) format to specify the date.
```

This should be the case for all major browsers.

Comment: This looks like it worked.  I didn't even think about it because I tried the login, then looked at the cookie in IE developer tools and thought it looked like Path was set correctly.  Looks like explicitly adding Path to options worked, though.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where logout would not work on IE9, using Gorilla sessions (although login worked fine).

I eventually discovered that IE was caching the responses to my API endpoints and sending the cached (304 NOT MODIFIED) API responses to the client, even though the cookie values where changing.

Forcing the API endpoints to never be cached fixed the problem:

```
w.Header().Set("Expires", "Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00 GMT")
w.Header().Set("Last-Modified", "{now} GMT")
w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate")
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful to me.  Adding these lines forced IE to send out new requests for data just like the other browsers do.