# golang session variables not working. what am i doing incorrectly?

Tags: session, go

I am using the gorilla/sessions package to  implement sessions. the relevant code (or at least what I think is the only relevant part) is as follows:

```
// Function handler for executing HTML code
func lobbyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request)  {
    if isLoggedIn := validateSession(w, req); isLoggedIn {
        lobbyTempl.Execute(w, req.Host)
    } else {
        homeTempl.Execute(w, map[string]string{
            "loginErrors": "Must log in first",
        })
    } 
}

// Serves the files as needed, whenever they are requested
//      used for all images, js, css, and other static files
func sourceHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func loginHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    un, pw := r.FormValue("lUn"), r.FormValue("lPw")
    if usr := findUser(un, pw); usr != nil {
        if createSession(w, r) {
            http.Redirect(w, req, "/lobby.html", http.StatusFound)
        }
    } else {
        homeTempl.Execute(w, map[string]string{
            "loginErrors": "User not found",
        }) 
    }
}

func createSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) bool {
    session, _ := store.Get(r, sessionName)
    session.Values["isAuthorized"] = true
    if err := session.Save(r, w); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("saving error: ", err.Error())
        return false
    }

    return true
}

func validateSession(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) bool {
    if session, err := store.Get(r, sessionName); err == nil {
        if v, ok := session.Values["isAuthorized"]; ok && v == true {
            fmt.Println("Authorized user identified!")
            return true
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Unauthorized user detected!")
            return false
        }
    }

    return false
}

func main() {
    //...

    // serving files for the game
    http.HandleFunc("/", homeHandler)    
    http.Handle("/ws", websocket.Handler(wsLobbyHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/lobby.html", lobbyHandler)
    http.HandleFunc("/formlogin", loginHandler)
    //...
    //http.HandleFunc("/*.html", SourceHandler)
    if err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(*addr, "cert.pem", "key.pem", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe:", err)
    }
}`
```

in my html i have:

```
<form id="login_form" action="/formlogin" method="post">
```

When logging in, the request is handled within loginHandler

The user is identified correctly from the database and a session is created (via createSession()) and placed into the cookie store.

But after the redirect to lobby.html, back in loginHandler

```
http.Redirect(w, req, "/lobby.html", http.StatusFound)
```

the validation within lobbyHandler does not work. Does this have to do with the store.Save(...) altering the headers?

I'm very new to go, as well as web apps in  general, so I would really appreciate feedback.

Comment: is `sessionName` defined elsewhere in the code?

Comment: Sorry, a non Go question: Have you watched this in anything like Firebug or Chrome's inspector? You can check the cookie headers and values before and after the login. Also, you don't seem to be setting any cookie options (Secure, HttpOnly etc.) I don't think it'll be related, but it may affect some browsers. Have a look at the Session.Options (https://github.com/gorilla/sessions/blob/master/sessions.go#L24). Example `if session.IsNew {
  session.Options.Secure = true
 }`

Comment: which version of go you are using ? which browser ? 
check out this code, and try to run it on your environment
[http://play.golang.org/p/sNdYCMhOwN](http://play.golang.org/p/sNdYCMhOwN)
on mine its working as expected

Comment: Intermernet: yes sessionName is defined elsewhere

and I have not used Firebug/Chrome inspector for cookies. Thanks for the heads up on the cookie options. I have changed options.

i am using Go1.1 on Chrome.

Comment: On the off chance someone else is having a similar problem - check your browser isn't denying session cookies (like mine was...)  - especially from localhost - I had to set to "allow" in firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, i was able to stumble across a similar [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053699/go-and-gorilla-sessions-in-internet-explorer?rq=1) that works for me.

```
session.Options = &sessions.Options{
    Path: "/lobby.html",
}
```

I needed to make sure the cookies know where they are going to be redirected properly.